# How do I use awk or sed to search a list of words and insert to new line?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

thanks to all recommend it work for me

My files:

**File1.sh  (bash shell)**

prefix_ud=uname;

path_file=/path/filescript;

sed -i "$(grep -n 'uname.*' "$path_file" |tail -1|cut -f1 -d':')a "$prefix_ud"     yahoo.com" "$path_file"

sed -i "$(grep -n 'uname.*' "$path_file" |tail -1|cut -f1 -d':')a "$prefix_ud"     twitter.com" "$path_file"

**File2  Expected output:**

```
text1
text2
uname google.com
uname gmail.com
uname hotmail.com

uname yahoo.com

uname twitter.com

text3
text4
```

Comment: You would have to be way more explicit. What's the process between file1 and file2? What do you mean by "new insert"?

Comment: Don't you have the input and output files reversed?

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, i would like to add the word to file2 line name that prefix uname "     "

the "new insert" mean  word from the file1 please

sorry, I am not a good english  i will try all recommended  thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugly, but I think this is what OP wants:

Create a temp file  with the "uname" attached to every line:

```
sed 's/^/uname /' file_1 > tmp_file
```

Save the last ocurrence of "uname..." from `file_2` in a variable:

```
last=$(awk '/uname.*/{a=$0}END{print a}' file_1)
```

Add after the last occurrence the contents of `tmp_file`

```
sed -e "/$last/rtmp_file" file_2
```

Output:

```
text1
text2
uname google.com
uname gmail.com
uname hotmail.com
uname yahoo.com
uname twitter.com
text3
text4
```

Comment: What are the contents of the file `file_1`? the OP hasn't provided it.

Comment: thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really match your expected output. `sed` can handle things like:

```
sed 's/.*twitter.com/uname & Stuff/;s/.*yahoo.com/uname & Stuff/' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

`&` will append to the end, note the literal space.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants.

Comment: thanks you very much